# Next.js does not delete dynamic page deleted in CMS

Tags: next.js, contentful, contentful-api

I am using next.js 10 and have a [slug] page which creates dynamic pages from Contentful CMS.
I am changing the slug inside CMS and run `next dev` the old slug correctly returns 404 and the new slug works.
However when I build and run `next start` the old slug still returns a cached page, the new slug works properly.
I am returning revalidate 10 and have assumed the page should refresh after 10sec

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<SlugRoutePageProps> = async ({
  params,
}) => {
  ....  
  ....
  const pageData = await getPageData(params.slug)
  if (pageData.total === 0) return { notFound: true }

  return {
    props: {
      pageType: "DynamicPage",
      pageProps: {
        pageData,
      },
      revalidate: 10,
    },
  }
}
```

in `getStaticPaths` I have `fallback: "blocking"`, also tried `fallback: true` with no difference.

Edit:
`getPageData` is a basic call to the contentful api - no caching

```
   const getPageData = async (
      slug: string,
    ): Promise<FetchPagesResult> => {
      const client = createContentfulClient()
      return client.getEntries<Page>({
        content_type: "page",
        "fields.slug": slug,
        include: 5,
        order: "-sys.updatedAt",
        limit: 1,
      })
    }
```

Comment: Have you check your api cache? Please provide getPageData function code and the server side as well

Comment: I have added the getPageData function in my question - it doesn't do anything fancy - just a basic contentful api call with no caching - I don't think it causes the problem

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution yet? I have a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864802/next-js-isr-page-not-being-deleted-after-deleting-it-in-cms